1D 2-step finite square potential barrier
I need to solve this problem. Given a one dimensional 2 step potential barrier and have to write the time-independent Schrödinger equation for the 4 intervals. Before zero, from zero to a, from a to 2a, after 2a. We studied the single step case, and also the 2 barriers with a gap between them but don't know how to handle this. The potential is zero if x<0, V_0 between 0 and a, 2V_0 between a and 2a, and zero again if x>2*a.


Is the goal just to write out the equations or to solve them as well?

The goal is to write and solve, but i think i can solve after get help to write it correctly.

I think the problem set up will look something like this.
Start with the time-independent Schrodinger equation (eigenvalue equation)
$$ E \psi(x) = - \frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} \psi(x)  + V(x) \psi(x)$$
Because $V(x)$ is defined piecewise we break this up into four regions,
$$ \psi''_1(x) = -\frac{2m}{\hbar^2} E \psi_1(x) \text{  for } x < 0$$
$$ \psi''_2(x) =  \frac{2m}{\hbar^2} (V_0 -E) \psi_2(x) \text{  for } 0 < x < a$$
$$ \psi''_3(x) =  \frac{2m}{\hbar^2} (2V_0 -E) \psi_3(x) \text{  for } 0 < x < a$$
$$ \psi''_4(x) = -\frac{2m}{\hbar^2} E \psi_4(x)\text{  for }  x > 2a$$
This will be supplemented by boundary conditions at all three boundaries which come from requiring that the wave function and it's derivatives are continuous across the boundaries.
The derivative must be continuous because $V(x)$ is not singular (e.g. a delta function) at the boundaries.
Explicitly the boundary conditions will be
$$ \psi_1(0) = \psi_2(0), \psi_1'(0) = \psi_2'(0)$$
$$ \psi_2(a) = \psi_3(a), \psi_2'(a) = \psi_3'(a)$$
$$ \psi_3(2a) = \psi_4(2a), \psi_3'(2a) = \psi_4'(2a)$$
These should be straightforward, though tedious, to solve.
You will probably have to break the solution up into cases where $E <V_0$, $V_0< E<2V_0$, $E > 2V_0$. I am guessing the next step would be to solve for the reflection and transmission coefficients, which will come from the coefficients on your solutions $\psi_1$ and $\psi_4$.
